# Import "blocktunes" could not be resolved Pylance report Missing Imports

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-urls

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from blocktunes import views     #error in blocktunes

urlpatterns = [

    path('', include('blocktunes.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.UserRegister_view)
```

]

Why is it showing missing imports?

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'blocktunes.apps.blocktunesConfig',  
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
```

]

PLEASE HELP.

Image link of structure of apps
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YhPEg.png

Answer (score 0):

By adding the following command in .vscode of the folder, I was able to import blocktunes.

```
 "python.analysis.extraPaths": ["./etherly"]
```